# PHP syntax error in different versions

Tags: php, syntax-error

I sometimes get values from an array like this: `$var = array ('key1' => 'value1')['key1'];` , so `$var` should be equal to `value1`

I run code like this in a server having PHP v5.4.16 , for example, `explode ('-', $str)[0];` and it works fine. 
Now if I transfer this code to another server which uses PHP v5.3.10 I get an error `(syntax error): syntax error, unexpected '[' ...`

Is this because of the version? (I don't think so because the difference between versions is so small..), or some setting in the server?
Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: PHP 5.4 adds the short array syntax.

Comment: So it's all about the version? Ok thank you (Y)

Comment: It has nothing to do with short array syntax but with array dereferencing.

Comment: @MichalBrašna That's right. "Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. foo()[0]". See http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Comment: I found this according to @MichalBrašna http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-89

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it depends on the version of PHP you are running. As [PHP docs mentions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a
> function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a
> temporary variable.
>
> As of PHP 5.5 it is possible to array dereference an array literal.

In PHP 5.3 you would have to use

```
$exploded = explode('-', $str);
$first = $exploded[0];
// or
list($first,) = explode('-', $str);
```

In PHP 5.4 and later you can use

```
$first = explode('-', $str)[0];
```